# Analysis of Data in SQL using R

Tags: sql, r

I have table inside a database with more than 52 million rows.
When I load the whole data in r using the following code:

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};
server=bi-prd-dw;database=BV_Coll;trusted_connection=yes;")`

dataFetchEUR <- sqlFetch(cn, 'BV_Report', colnames=FALSE, rows_at_time=1000)
```

It results to an error stating: 
**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 500.0 Mb**

Now, my question is instead of loading the whole table in R is there a way I can conduct statistical analysis directly to the table using R?

Or is the only way to analyze whole data set is to load the it directly in R?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an ideal situation to do the heavy lifting in the database instead of in R.  For instance, `dplyr` can generate SQL queries to do this: https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/

Comment: This is really needing to be closed as a package recommendation request but you should look at the `sqldf` package.See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask